# Excel column will not populate when I transfer data to it via Access VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, etl

I set up a data transfer from Access --> Excel using VBA.

The Access query output is 9 columns across, and returns a dynamic number of rows.

All columns except the 8th column are being copied into the Excel worksheet. The 8th column does not get populated with anything.

During the data transfer, no errors or warnings get thrown.

My VBA code is below:

```
    ''Reference: Microsoft ActiveX Data Object x.x Library
    Dim rs4 As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim xl4 As Object ''Excel.Application
    Dim wb4 As Object ''Workbook

    Set xl4 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Set wb4 = xl4.Workbooks.Open(Path & fileName & Format(getAsOfDate(), "MMDDYYYY") & fileType)

    ''Connection relevant for 2007 or 2010
    rs4.Open "myQuery", CurrentProject.AccessConnection

    wb4.Sheets("myWorksheet").Cells(9, 3).CopyFromRecordset rs4     ''Cells(down, across)

    xl4.Visible = False

    wb4.Close SaveChanges:=1
    rs4.Close

    Set wb4 = Nothing
    Set xl4 = Nothing
    Set rs4 = Nothing
```

A screenshot of the Excel (macro enabled) workbook is below. Please note - the column that won't accept data is outlined by a red box. Also note - this column's cells have a drop-down box where the user can manually select values. However, the column to its right also has cells with drop-down functionality, and data is able to get transferred into it successfully.

I also tried sending the data from Access formatted as (1) a text string, (2) an int. No difference.

[image]

**Edit**: I swapped the last 2 columns in my Access query (Col8 <--> Col9) and transmitted the query results to Excel. Now I noticed that Col8 (formerly Col9) is appearing correctly, and col9 (formerly Col8) is not not appearing.

This points to the Access query being at fault.

Here is the code that generates the faulty Access column:

`Iif(table.ID like "9*","0",Iif(table.ID like "3*","1",NULL))`

What about this is causing the column output to be incompatible in Excel? In Access, the results show with no fault.

**Solution**:

For some reason, using the `like` operator in the sql was causing the column transfer to fail. I updated the sql to the following, and the data transferred successfully:

`IIf(left(table.ID,1) = "9","0", IIf(left(table.ID,1) = "3","1",NULL))`

Comment: If you remove the validation from the cells in Col8 does the data transfer?

Comment: I removed validation from all the cells in Col8, and it's still not populating.

Comment: Is the source table column of a different type from the others?  I think you'd need to add a lot more detail here before people can make any kind of informed guess.

Comment: The column that cannot transmit successfully shares datatypes with other successful columns in both the source and destination. There is a successful column that has an identical source datatype and destination datatype (as well as destination validation rule) as the faulty column.

Comment: Have you tried swapping the order of the columns (eg swap #8 with #9) and see if the same column is missing when in a different position?  Any event handlers on the sheet which might be clearing the data after it's been transferred?

Comment: There either has to be a problem with your excel shhet or (more probable) withyour access data. Try exchange the data from row 8 and row 9 in the access-query and see which excel column is filed

Comment: Tim, Johanness, I will swap columns 8 and 9 in Access and will let you know what happens when I transmit to Excel. Thanks again for your time spent.

Comment: Tim, Johanness, please see my latest edit.

Comment: i found a solution; see updated post. thanks again for your suggestions.